# mysql conditional executing statement

Tags: mysql, sql, replication

From [this post](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/leader-election-using-mysql), we can do leader election with MySQL, but I don't know if we can do fencing in MySQL. That is: let MySQL determine if the client is primary master or not. Consider following case: server A, B, C formed a quorum, and A is primary master, at certain moment, A is not primary anymore, but A doesn't know, and issued an insert statement, we need to prevent that.

So I'm wondering if we can change SQL statements into something like:

`IF i'm primary master
  do xxx
ENDIF`

Comment: You probably want to use [MySQL Cluster](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/) for this, unless you already are?

Comment: @tadman well, the problem here is not about MySQL, so I do not care if MySQL is cluster or not. What I want is a way to prevent client writing to MySQL, or how to express that in SQL language.

Comment: If you're trying to do the opposite, coordinate a cluster through MySQL, you might be fighting an uphill battle. This is a solved problem with a tool like [Heartbeat](http://linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat) which is much better suited to the task since it implements those algorithms correctly.

Comment: You can put it in the WHERE clause . In example `UPDATE A set X= 1 WHERE  Primary = {currentState}`. Or even better use MERGE.